# Wake on LAN prevents sleep mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, wake-on-lan

The Wake on LAN (WOL) feature of my [Intel 82579V Gigabit LAN adapter](http://www.intel.com/support/ethernetcomponents/controllers/82579/sb/CS-032239.htm) is working great in case my Windows 7 PC is powered off.

But because my network card is able to wake my PC I can’t use the sleep mode. All traffic directed to my IP wakes the PC.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsure what your exact version of Windows is, but [this site seems to indicate a similar issue is connected to “Wake on pattern match”](http://jack.ukleja.com/fix-for-windows-7-random-wake-from-sleep-problem/) issues in Windows 7. And the solution appears to be to disable “Wake on pattern match” under the advanced properties tab for that network adapter as shown below:

[image]

The Intel adapter panel has the “Wake on Pattern Match” option in the power management tab:

[image]

As for what “Wake on pattern match” actually is, [this answer covers it nicely](https://superuser.com/a/560178/167207); it’s basically a lot of basic network activity:

> The “Wake on pattern match” option instead checks for packets that
>   matches the *operating-system-specified* patterns; for example, an ARP
>   request for the computer’s address, or a TCP connection attempt.

In contrast, a [“magic packet”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) is a unique an—as implied—magical/non-standard bit of network communication designed specifically for unique needs of wake on LAN setups:

> The magic packet is a broadcast frame containing anywhere within its
>   payload 6 bytes of all 255 (FF FF FF FF FF FF in hexadecimal),
>   followed by sixteen repetitions of the target computer's 48-bit MAC
>   address, for a total of 102 bytes.